# js Как определенной ссылке задать href из хэша сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Как для ссылки <a href="" id="mylink" - задать спец ссылку, которая состоит из текущего моего хэша страница и перед ним например добавить real/qwe/

То есть у меня сейчас открыта страница с хэшем: ?filters=do-morya%5B21%5D
а мне нужно, что бы в мою спец ссылку с id=mylink изменился href
в таком виде: /real/qwe/?filters=do-morya%5B21%5D

Спасибо

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, хэш это то, что после #, а элементы после ? - это search parameters (поисковые параметры).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.org/?filters=do-morya%5B21%5D');

const link = document.querySelector('#mylink');

link.setAttribute('href', `/real/qwe/${url.search}`);

console.log(link.getAttribute('href'));
```

```html
<a href="" id="mylink">mylink</a>
```